# ¿Por qué el límite numérico de enteros en JS es entre -(2^53 - 1) y 2^53 - 1?

Tags: javascript

Como todos sabrán, en `JS` el límite de enteros es de `[ -((2**53)-1) , (2**53)-1]`, es decir, `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` a `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, y lo único que quiero es saber *el porqué* de esto. ¿Se debe a alguna restricción de los navegadores? ¿Se debe a que simplemente se pensó que los números que no entrasen en ese rango no eran lo suficientemente comunes como para programar su uso?

Comment: la respuesta es sencilla, el *porqué* son los bytes, viene de antes de los navegadores, viene de muy lejos el por qué, no estoy seguro pero creo que viene desde los primeros ordenadores y su limitación. Por eso existen diferentes tipos de integers, acorde a los bytes que se van a usar, en lenguajes altos no tenemos mucho en cuenta el uso de cpu/memoria, pero para lenguajes de bajo nivel el tipo es muy importante

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/561/16597)

Comment: Es por el *Tamaño de [Palabra](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palabra_%28informática%29)*.

Answer (score 3):

No tengo claro si la pregunta es adecuada para el sitio pero según [la documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

> La constante MAX_SAFE_INTEGER tiene un valor de 9007199254740991
> (9,007,199,254,740,991 o ~9 mil billones). El razonamiento detrás de
> ese número es que JavaScript usa números flotantes de doble precisión
> tal como está especificado en IEEE 754 por lo que puedes representar
> números de forma segura entre -(2^53 - 1) y  2^53 - 1.

Puedes echarle un ojo al resumen que hace Wikipedia de la [IEEE 754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).
Y aquí te explican exactamente el [formato en coma flotante de doble precisión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formato_en_coma_flotante_de_doble_precisi%C3%B3n) con más detalle.